# Print Area In Flash AS2?

Tags: flash, printing, actionscript-2

Am i able to print a certain area with actionscript-2 , i have an old flash presentation which i need to add such a functinality to it , i can't switch to AS3 ,

in AS3 this could be done easily like this

```
var printArea:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 600, 850);
var printOptions:PrintJobOptions = new PrintJobOptions(false);
myPrintJobObject.addPage(myMovieClip, printArea, printOptions, 1);
```

does anyone know any **workaround with AS2** ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really simple example that will hopefully help you:

```
var printJobObject:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
printJobObject.addPage(myMovieClip, {xMin: 0, xMax:0, yMin:0, yMax:0});
```

Also if that doesn't help there is more information about it here: [ActionScript 2.0 Language Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001452.html)